# Designing a DAO which reads a huge amount of data

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

This might be a little open-ended (and subjective) question - but please bear with me.

I have a DAO which can potentially load a huge amount of data - this could lead to OutOfMemoryExceptions. All entities are mutually exclusive, and can be simultaneously processed - basically, the caller doesn't need to get the data-set at once.

I am looking for a way to return chunks of data to caller (to avoid the DAO holding a lot of data in memory).

So far I have come up with two possible solutions:

1. The caller provides a consumer (a functional interface implementation), which the DAO calls when lot of data has been read (a threshold limit is crossed). The DAO passes the data to this consumer (called in a separate thread), clears it's own copy of data and continues retrieving rest of the data.
2. The caller and DAO share a BlockingQueue. The DAO puts each entity retrieved in the queue. The caller periodically polls for this data from the queue - I am not clear how to implement this cleanly. For e.g., when to stop polling the queue etc. (not a road-blocker though).

If you have stayed with me till now, thank you. Please let me know what you think, and if there's any better solution to this.

UPDATE:

I am not inclined towards using pagination. Each entity retrieved is quite heavy and I would very much like to avoid sorting it.

Comment: it sounds that all you want is pagination?

Comment: Pagination can help me read the data from database - how would I use it to return chunks of data to DAO's caller?

Comment: read about pagination dude, it returns a `page` of data for you

Comment: you can just cache the whole thing during server start up ....we have over a million records and it caches fine with no issues... if you face a OutOfMemoryException just increase the perGem space in tomcat 'Java VM options. -XX:PermSize<size> ' .... or go the pagination way like the others mentioned

Comment: I would avoid using caching the data - this data changes quite frequently and can be stale quite soon.

Comment: @rohitthomas - I read your comment again - it is never advisable to "just increase the permgem space". One must see if it can be avoided, and whether the application can be optimised.